# Using PathMenu with SVG in a Paintcode StyleKit

Tags: svg, menu, paintcode

I need to change the image programmatically that PathMenu uses to design.
I have a PaintCode generated StyleKit which draws .SVG files, not an image in a Asset.xcassets.

PathMenu uses something like this to take the images:

```
    let menuItemImage = UIImage(named: "bg-menuitem")!
```

but I need to make something like

```
     let menuItemImage = myImageFromMyStyleKit
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PaintCode document, select canvas and in Inspector, select *StyleKit Image Method* from dropdown menu in *Code Export* section.

[image: Canvas Code Export]

This canvas will then generate `imageOfCanvas...` method, instead of `drawCanvas...` method. This way, you can then simply obtain image of this canvas and use it in the menu item.

```
PathMenuItem(image: StyleKit.imageOfCanvas)
```